# Using `this` as a generic type on a static method

Tags: typescript

This is the block of JavaScript I am unable to convert to TypeScript:

```js
class Base {
  constructor(value) {
    this._value = value
  }
  static of(value) {
    return new this(value)
  }
}

class Extended extends Base {
  valueOf() {
    return this._value
  }
}

const data = 888
const e = Extended.of(data)
const v = e.valueOf()
```

Some things about the code:

- The type of `data` is unknown. Can be string, number, object, anything really.
- Multiple classes will extend the `Base`.
- `e` should be of type `Extended<number>` (because `data` is a number).
- The type of `v` should match the type of `data`.

I was hoping to be able to do this without re-creating the `of` method in all classes that extend `Base`.

My failed attempts:

1. Kind of works, but without generic argument.

   ```js
   class Base {
     static of<D extends Base>(this: { new(): D }) {
       return new this()
     }
   }

   class Extended extends Base {
     valueOf() {
       return 123
     }
   }

   const b = Base.of()
   const e = Extended.of()
   const v = e.valueOf()
   ```
2. `e` becomes `Extended<unknown>` and `v` is `unknown`.

   ```js
   class Base<T> {
     protected _value: T

     constructor(value: T) {
       this._value = value;
     }

     static of<V, D extends Base<V>>(this: { new(value: V): D }, value: V) {
       return new this(value)
     }
   }

   class Extended<T> extends Base<T> {
     valueOf(): T {
       return this._value;
     }
   }

   const data = 888
   const e = Extended.of(data); // Extended<unknown>
   const v = e.valueOf(); // unknown
   ```
3. This works, except `of` has to be recreated in every class that extends.

   ```js
   class Base<T> {
     protected _value: T

     constructor(value: T) {
       this._value = value;
     }

     static of<V>(value: V) {
       return new Base(value)
     }
   }

   class Extended<T> extends Base<T> {
     static of<V>(value: V) {
       return new Extended(value)
     }
     valueOf(): T {
       return this._value;
     }
   }

   const data = 888
   const e = Extended.of(data);
   const v = e.valueOf();
   ```

Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Without [microsoft/TypeScript#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) to support static `this` (or [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) to support higher-kinded types) I doubt you'll find anything that isn't a semi-broken workaround.  I can't find anything better than what you already have, at any rate.