# Async JS constructor via static "create" method – TypeScript types problem

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working on the universal abstraction/base of the async constructor and it works fine with JavaScript.

But I'm stuck with correct TypeScript types, it should work like this:

```
const a: AnyClass = await AnyClass.create();
```

It works fine in JavaScript, but TypeScript types are wrong (missing at the moment).

Example of the similar class called `DbConnection`:

```
class DbConnection extends AsyncConstructor<[serverId: number, url: string]> {
    #serverId: number;
    #connection: Connection;

    protected constructor(serverId: number, url: string) {
        super(serverId, url);
        this.#serverId = serverId;
    }

    protected override async constructorAsync(serverId: number, url: string): Promise<void> {
        this.#connection = await DB.connect(url);
    }
}
```

The base class is:

```
class AsyncConstructor<CtorParams extends any[]> {
    protected constructor(...args: CtorParams) {}

    protected async constructorAsync(...args: CtorParams): Promise<void> {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }

    // =-->>> MISSING TYPES FOR THE NEXT METHOD: <<<--=
    static async create(...args: CtorParams) {
        const res = new this(...args);
        await res.constructorAsync(...args);
        return res;
    }
}
```

What type to specify for the return of the `create` method?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68027725/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe not really, since it doesn't provide any solution, at least partial. Also JavaScript version works perfectly.

Comment: I didn't say it provided a solution, I said it was related. The comment from jcalz explains why there likely isn't (or at least wasn't) a solution. And whether or not the JS works isn't the question - TS disallows plenty of things that work in JS, usually on purpose.

Comment: This comment on the github issue that's linked describes a factory method as well: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863#issuecomment-181593546

Immediately above that comment is a solution with generics that's a little verbose but it might do the trick.

Comment: Btw, `constructorAsync` should not be a method. Instead of calling this method after the instantiation to initialise your `#connection`, better call a static `createConnection()` method *before* calling the constructor, and then pass the awaited connection as an argument to `new this()`.

Comment: @Bergi yes this works (e.g. static method `createConnection()`), and this is actually how half of the similar implementations works. But it is unique to each class, and name, like "createConnection" is also unique (not possible to have interface that requires static members), so that's why this question was created. But looks like it is impossible at the moment. Thanks for proposal

Comment: Thanks @KernelDeimos jonrsharpe and Bergi for suggestions! I posted answer by my own - *it is impossible to achieve at the moment*

Comment: "*not possible to have interface that requires static members*" - not during the inheritance/`implements` declaration, but it is possible to require them during the `create` invocation. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/72771370/1048572 for example. Here, it could be something like `async create<T>(this: { new(c: Connection): T; createConnection(): Promise<Connection> }): T { return new this(await this.createConnection()); }`

Answer (score 0):

**This is impossible as of 2024.02 due to the limitation of the TypeScript (for sure <= v.5.3)**

---

- As suggested by [@KernelDeimos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4933274/kerneldeimos) there is an open issue at the TypeScript repository - [Polymorphic "this" for static members #5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863#issuecomment-181593546)
- And by [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78041904/async-js-constructor-via-static-create-method-typescript-types-problem#comment137582739_78041904) there is *"similar"* problem described here - [Using `this` as a generic type on a static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68027725/using-this-as-a-generic-type-on-a-static-method)

---

The only possible *partial* solution as for now is:

```
class DbConnection  {
    #serverId: number;
    #connection: Connection;

    static async create(serverId: number, url: string): Promise<DbConnection> {
        const connection = await DB.connect(url);
        const res = new DbConnection(serverId, url, connection);        
        return res;
    }

    protected constructor(serverId: number, connection: Connection) {        
        this.#serverId = serverId;
        this.#connection = connection;
    }
}
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that you:

- cannot force some classes to follow the same implementation
- as a result, each class may have its unique name and way of creation
- this may cause problems during the inheritance of complex classes, especially with the big code base